# ServiceStack: Handler for request not found?

Tags: servicestack

I have three routes defined. First two work fine but the last one returns error in the subject.

```
    Routes.Add<FeeInstructionsList>("/policies/{clientPolicyId}/feeinstructions", "GET");
    Routes.Add<FeeInstructionsEdit>("/policies/{clientPolicyId}/feeinstructions/{feetype}", "GET");
    Routes.Add<List<FeeInstructionEditInfo>>("/policies{clientPolicyId}/feeinstructions", "POST");
```

When I had third route as just "/feeinstructions", it worked fine, but when I added route as above it does not work.

FeeInstructionEditInfo does not have memeber called "clientPolicyId". Could that be a reason. If so, how do I pass it to service without requiring to modify my dto. Can it be additional parameter on the service operation like this. I don't this it is possible as ss is one dto per request, but maybe there is a way?

```
public List<FeeInstructionEditInfo> Post(int clientPolicyId, List<FeeInstructionEditInfo> request)
```

Currently this method is declared as

```
public List<FeeInstructionEditInfo> Post(List<FeeInstructionEditInfo> request)
```

This is the request being sent

```
> POST http://localhost:12543/api/policies/680455600/feeinstructions/
> HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/json Accept-Language: en-US
> Referer: http://localhost:12543/ClientBin/SR.SRUnite.ShellUI.xap
> Content-Length: 1408 Accept-Encoding: identity Accept:
> application/json User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0;
> Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; BOIE9;ENUS) Host: localhost:12543
> Connection: Keep-Alive Pragma: no-cache
```

These are my original dtos, and these have not changed

```
 [Route("/policies/{clientPolicyId}/feeinstructions/{feetype}","GET")]
 public class FeeInstructionsEdit
 {
     public int ClientPolicyId { get; set; }
     public string FeeType { get; set; }
 }

 public class FeeInstructionsEditResponse
 { 
     public List<KeyValuePair> Instructions { get; set; }
     public List<KeyValuePair> Contacts { get; set; }
     public List<FeeInstructionEditInfo> FeeInstructions { get; set; }       
 }

public partial class FeeInstructionEditInfo
{
    public int FeeInstructionId { get; set; }

    public string FeeTypeCode { get; set; }
    public string FeeTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public string FeeTypeGroupCode { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string InsuredType { get; set; }
    public string Demographic { get; set; }
    public string Instruction { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public decimal? FeeAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I would post  list of FeeInstructionEditInfo to /clientPolicies/342434/feeinstructions and it would not work, but posting to /feeinstructions would.

I now post using this pair of dto's.

```
 [Route("feeinstructions","POST")]
 public class FeeInstructionsSave
 {
     public int ClientPolicyId { get; set; }
     public List<FeeInstructionEditInfo> FeeInstructions { get; set; }
 }

 public class FeeInstructionsSaveResponse : IHasResponseStatus
 {
      public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: `[Route("feeinstructions","POST")]` should have a `/` prefix e.g. `/feeinstructions`. This should be a startup error in [recent versions of ServiceStack](https://plus.google.com/u/0/106787359118990653189/posts/gVn3cccmMHt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [fundamental concept](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/What-is-a-message-based-web-service?) in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) is that **every service**  needs to be called with a **Request DTO**. This Request DTO can be populated with any combination of PathInfo, QueryString and Request Body.

This means if you wanted to pass in a collection you would need to have your Request DTO inherit from it, e.g:

```
[Route("/policies/{clientPolicyId}/feeinstructions", "POST")]
public class EditFeeInstructions : List<FeeInstructionEditInfo>
{
}
```

Now everything behaves as normal:

```
public List<FeeInstructionEditInfo> Post(EditFeeInstructions request)
{
   ...
}
```

For an Empty Request your service would look like:

```
public class EmptyRequest {} 

public object Post(EmptyRequest request)
{
   ...
}
```

Even if you want to [process the request manually yourself](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization), you would still need to provide a Request DTO signalling your intent, e.g:

```
public class Hello : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    //The raw Http Request Input Stream gets injected here
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think that I might have not given you enough info to answer. I understand that fundamental concept. I updated my question with how I had it originally, and how I have it now.

Comment: Routes components must be separated by `/` or `.` separators, you can't have a partial word match like you're attempting. Please see docs on [Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) for more info.

Comment: @mytz: Ha, that was a typo, there should have been "/", I was not trying partial match. Thanks.